# return statements in recursive calls

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, binary-search-tree

From what I understand about recursive calls, is that when you are recursing into by calling the function ,the statement needs to be a return statement ,because basically when it pops out of the function stack it expects some value from the earlier call .

I have some code like for inserting in a BST

```
insertCorrectLocation(root, newNode) {
    if (newNode.data < root.data) {
        if (root.left == null) {
            root.left = newNode
        } else {
            return this.insertCorrectLocation(root.left, newNode)
        }
    }
    else {
        if (root.right == null) {
            root.right = newNode
        } else {
            return this.insertCorrectLocation(root.right, newNode)
        }
    }
}
```

This works even if I remove the return statements for the calls ,such as

```
else {
    if (root.right == null) {
        root.right = newNode
    } else {
        this.insertCorrectLocation(root.right, newNode)
    }
}
```

How does that happen ?

Answer (score 8):

In a recursive function, you only need to (explicitly) `return` if the outer *consumer* of the recursive function needs to receive a value, for example:

```
const foundNode = tree.findNode(5);
```

In this case, since you're only inserting a value, but not retrieving one, there's no need for recursive `return`s.

(functions will automatically return once they reach the end of their block if there's no `return` statement, passing control back to the caller)

Answer (score 4):

There is no requirement to `return` any values from a function that is mainly for side effects. Recursive functions have no special treatments so it goes for those as well. eg. `console.log` is mainly for effect and it returns the default value `undefined`. Thus in your example where a recursive function alters an existing object will be able to use the root node as the whole tree after the process has finished.

The most common error is when the contract is supposed to return a value and you forget to return in some places. Eg.

```
function factorial(n) {
  if (n === 1) return 1;

  factorial(n - 1) * n;
}

factorial(1) ; //==> 1
factorial(2) ; //==> undefined
```

A function that does not explicitly return a value always return `undefined`. Thus for a factorial returning `undefined` is clearly a bug, but it did rewind the stack and did all the calculations, only that it didn't use the result.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with everything said about not needing an explicit return in recursive function.

But I'm currently looking at a huge recursive function, about 600 lines, with many if-else statements. I think it can be dangerous for long recursive functions to **not explicitly return**. And while I know there are other problems with a long recursive function, it really doesn't hurt to just `return;`, especially that is the intention.

Comment: I don't understand how `return` has anything to do with safety for "long" recursive functions. If the logic is so confusing that you have to toss in `return` "just in case" you have a control flow bug, the function needs to be simplified. OP is asking why some recursive functions work even without `return` and others require `return`, and the reason is that the algorithm logic in this case doesn't depend on sub-results or return values. It mutates the tree in-place and every call frame only cares about parameters, not return values.